# JIRA C# SDK Connecting to JIRA

Tags: c#, jira

I'm using the Atlassian SDK from the following location: https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk

Right now, I'm simply trying to connect to my JIRA and just bring down some basic information like my tasks. Doing a quick google I found the following example: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/762516/Connecting-to-Jira-using-Csharp

In the above link, he connects to JIRA using the following line:

```
Jira jiraConn = new Jira("http://yourjiraurl.com/", jUserID, jPassword);
```

But when I try the same line:

```
 Jira jira = new Jira(url, "admin", "password");
```

I get the following errors:

> cannot convert from 'string' to 'Atlassian.Jira.ServiceLocator'
>
> cannot convert from 'string' to 'Atlassian.Jira.JiraCredentials'
>
> cannot convert from 'string' to 'Atlassian.Jira.JiraCache'

I've looked around to try and find some documentation on this, but I can't find anything relating to any of the 3 errors or what sort of syntax it is expecting. I would investigate the bitbucket more, but my works firewall has it blocked for unknown reasons.

Does anyone have any experience on combating these errors?

Comment: What is the type of `url`?

Comment: The url is of type var

Comment: The official page (which you linked) says to use `Jira.CreateRestClient("http://<your_jira_server>", "<user>", "<password>");` (so in your case: `Jira jira = Jira.CreateRestClient(url, "admin", "password");`)- I assume the codeproject example is outdated (as it used an older version of the SDK)

Comment: Sometimes, when looking for documentation, the best thing is to press F12 on the problem function.  That will take you to either the class or the interface, where your problems might be explained.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the prototype for Jira is:

```
Jira(ServiceLocator services, JiraCredentials credentials = null, JiraCache cache = null)
```

Then the errors you are getting are correct (strings are not JiraCredentials).
So either you need to create some credentials or you could use the other function:

```
public static Jira CreateRestClient(string url, string username = null, string password = null, JiraRestClientSettings settings = null)
```

So, something like:

```
Jira jira = Jira.CreateRestClient(url, "admin", "password");
```

Answer (score 1):

Not C# ... but this is how you can communicate with Atlassian.  This example is from a Google Sheet  (Just change the URL and endpoints).  I've done this a lot through VBA too over the years.   It seems like lately, the user / password has to be encoded.  I don't recall that being the case from earlier versions

```
function showAtlassian() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('atlassianform')
      .setWidth(200)
      .setHeight(200);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Atlassian Login');
}

function processAtlassian(myForm) {
  var username = myForm.un;
  var userpw = myForm.pw;
  var myencoded = Utilities.base64Encode(username+":"+userpw);
  var headers = {"Authorization" : "Basic " + myencoded};
  var options = {
      'method': 'get',
      "contentType" : "application/json",
      "headers": headers,
      'muteHttpExceptions': false
    }
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
url = 'https://---your domain---/wiki/rest/api/user/current';
  try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var data = JSON.parse(response)
    var result = ui.alert( 'got valid connection userkey ' + data.userKey );
  } catch(error) {
    var result = ui.alert( 'invalid user or password: url: '+ url +' err: ' + error.toString());
    getatlassian();
  }
}

function getatlassian() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  showAtlassian()
}
```