# Extract Jira data into SQL Server using SSIS in an automated process

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssis, jira, jira-rest-api

I have a task to get Jira data into our SQL Server via an automated process. There are two options that I can think of using SSIS (it is the only approved tool offered by my company):

1. Make a REST API (`GET` request) call in SSIS. To do this, I believe I will need to write a script task which is very challenging for me because I am not a code person. There are third party plugin tools (e.g. ZAPPYSYS) to call REST API and all you need is the URI and authentication in SSIS, but I don't think my company is going to approve another paid license just for this job.
2. Since our on-prem Jira is connected to Postgres, I was wondering if it is a valid option to extract Jira data from Postgres into SQL Server using SSIS? Something like: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2619/export-data-from-postgres-to-sql-server-using-ssis/

I am still very new to databases, ETL and technology in general, much appreciated if someone can let me know my option 2 is a valid option to try, or any guidance on writing the script task code for option 1.

Comment: On #1, they're either going to pay for a license or they're gonna pay for your time to code it. I ended up going with a Python script, turned into an .exe to do my jira work as ... I honestly don't recall - it's been 5 years. Seems like you should be able to make some hay from grabbing the SDK and having at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45102274/jira-c-sharp-sdk-connecting-to-jira  If you find code samples that tell you to nuget the package, that's going to be incomplete for SSIS as it doesn't retain the nuget package. You'll need to install the package to the GAC on your box & server