# VB.Net Forms App to Download Jira Tickets Data

Tags: .net, vb.net, jira

Howdee.

I am writing a small .NET app to connect to my Jira account and get all the issues and store them in a SQL Database for Invoicing and additional analytics.

I created a .NET Forms Project (in VB.NET as I know VB).

I have installed the NuGet Package for Jira
[image]

I have a module in my project where I will define all the Jira functions:
[image]

However I cant find any how to guides on how to use the Jira Object.

Any code samples, reference to proper HowTo Guides will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you had a look at their sdk docs: https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/src/6af77fe0531977c11f97231e49899e5a89cf0f8a/docs/how-to-use-the-sdk.md

Comment: Some more ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45102274/jira-c-sharp-sdk-connecting-to-jira

Comment: I have tried both those methods. I can connect to my Jira. But using the LINQ expression no issues are returned.